# PL/SQL: Use parameters within execute immediate

Tags: plsql, execute-immediate

I have a function like this (unfortunately, I cannot change it to send one array instead of multiple parameters):

```
CREATE FUNCTION (p1_ IN OUT VARCHAR2(100), p2_ IN OUT VARCHAR2(100), <...>, p10_ IN OUT VARCHAR2(100)
IS
BEGIN
    gather_value(p1_);
    gather_value(p2_);
    <...>
    gather_value(p8_);
END;
```

To clean it up a little bit, I would prefer to change the body as follows:

```
IS
stmt VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 .. 8
    LOOP
        stmt := 'gather_value(p:1_);'
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt USING i;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

However, in that case no such parameters are found.
Is there a way to work it around?

Comment: The only way I see you doing that is by putting all the parameters in an array (inside the body) ,,, and then using `for loop` and execute `immediate` `using` that array and the current `i`  index...

Comment: It was my first idea, but as I need to return their values (as they're out parameters), 8 assignment statements would be needed anyway.

Comment: There's no clear workaround to provide without understanding *why* you cannot change your function parameter signature.

Comment: Given that you have those 8 parameters and can't change them, the original static code is preferable to the fancy dynamic PL/SQL loop version anyway (IMHO).

Comment: The 8 individual `out` parameters make a  loop approach impossible. You can't loop over a set of parameters like this.